# Таймер для каждого пользователя сервером (HashMap)

Tags: java

Всем привет. Пытаюсь сделать бота для ВК. Застрял на таймере, так как не могу решить ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1445)
    at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:1469)
    at ru.ibusewinner.vk.souran.SouranBot$1.run(SouranBot.java:337)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Код метода с таймером:

```
private static void timer() {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(!cd.isEmpty()) {
                    for(TimerUser tUser : cd.keySet()) {
                        int time = cd.get(tUser);

                        if(time <= 0) {
                            cd.remove(tUser);
                        } else {
                            cd.put(tUser, time-1);
                            System.out.println("Челику "+tUser.getUuid()+" осталось жить: "+(time-1));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },1000,1000);
    }
```

Добавление synchronized в метод не помогло.

(TimerUser содержит id таймера (их у меня 2: на команды и на опыт) и UUID пользователя).

Comment: Нельзя делать удаление из коллекции, по которой вы делаете итерирование. Если очень надо, то используйте Iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так решится проблема:

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<TimerUser, Integer>> iterator = cd.entrySet().iterator();
                    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                        Map.Entry<TimerUser, Integer> entry = iterator.next();
                        if(entry.getValue() <= 0) {
                            iterator.remove();
                        } else {
                            entry.setValue(entry.getValue()-1);
                        }
                    }
```